# Perspective Transform Triangle Point

Tags: javascript, geometry, coordinates, transform, perspective

I am trying to find the equivalent point from one triangle to another.

[image: Triangle Equivalent Point]

Ideally I want to be able to give the 3 points of triangle A and the 3 points of triangle B which will then calculate the transform matrix which I can apply to the point afterwards to find the equivalent point.

I have found a few JavaScript libraries/methods for this, but they all use quadrilaterals rather than triangles and I am not sure what to do to apply to a triangle instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three point pairs can define affine transform, but can not define perspective one (four pairs [needed](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2008_fall/Papers/proj.pdf)).

How to find affine transform matrix using inverse matrix: [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844000/transfer-coordinates-from-one-triangle-to-another-triangle/18848074#18848074)  [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590244/find-affine-transformation-matrix-between-two-shapessvg-paths/33590658#33590658)