# Map point in triangle to another triangle in different coordinate system

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, latitude-longitude, affinetransform

[image]

I have two triangles in two different coordinate systems, where xa1,ya1 belongs to xb1, yb1 etc. So the triangle to the right corresponds to the triangle on the left in another system. The shape and positions are totally arbitrary, so the only thing I know is that Point `(xa1,ya1)` corresponds to Point `(xb1,yb1)`, `(xa2,ya2)` corresponds to `(xb2,yb2)` etc.

The first triangle is in a geographic coordinate system where I know latitude and longitude. The second triangle is in a coordinate system of 0 - 100.

**How can I find point `x` in the second triangle?**

1. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43509195/perspective-transform-triangle-point) similiar question, but it doesn't involve different coordinate sytems. Can this be done with «affine transformations»? Also, I would like to implement this in javascript and my mathematical knowledge is a bit limited, so you may need to explain this with a (pseudo-)code example.
2. It is a 10km x 10km area, so I hope geographical things can be simplified
3. If it can't be determined exactly, getting to know `x` as close as possible is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844000/transfer-coordinates-from-one-triangle-to-another-triangle/18848074#18848074) contains  formulas to calculate affine transformation.

Is it suitable for your case? Depends on 'different coordinate systems' real difference.

Perhaps you also can to try [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) - find these coordinates for point in the first system, then calculate cartesian coordinates using vertices in the second system. Result should be the same, because barycentric coordinates are affine invariant.

The first method is better when you need to transform a lot of points. For the only point you can try the second approach (not sure that it is faster).